# Sefiras HaOmer - if you know that you will miss a day

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer

Suppose someone knows that he will miss a day during Sefira (having surgery). Is it proper for him to count with a Bracha up until the day he will miss?

Comment: There is a very sad story of one of the _g'dolim_ who knew he would not make it to Shavu'os taking precautions against making the _b'racha_.

Comment: which one?................

Comment: Isn't this sort of analogous to the discussion about whether a boy who will become bar mitzvah during the Omer period should count with a berachah up to that point? As I understand it, one of the considerations there is whether each day is a separate mitzvah, or whether it's one that lasts for 49 days. (Though in that case there's also the discussion about whether his new Biblical obligation post-bar mitzvah can be seen as a continuation of his earlier Rabbinic one.)

Comment: By a boy that is becoming Bar Mitzva he is not going to miss a day, however over here the person will miss a day.

Comment: @Gershon Gold - The story is about Rav Breuer, and comes up around 10 minutes in to this shi'ur by Rav Willig: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/711258/Rabbi_Mordechai_I._Willig/The_Laws_of_Sefirat_HaOmer

Comment: In fact, that _shi'ur_ contains some great analysis that is relevant to answering the original question as well, including an interesting _chidush_ by Rav Zevin and another one by Rav Soloveitchik.

Comment: @WAF - Which R' Zevin?

Comment: @AdamMosheh I didn't know there were more than one, not do I remember his first name. He wrote several books about the _chagim_ that have been translated into English.

Comment: @WAF - I only know of one, and that is [the editor of the Encyclopedia Talmudit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Yosef_Zevin).  Actually, according to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Yosef_Zevin#Rabbinate_and_scholarship), his father was *Rabbi* Aharon Mordechai Zevin, so that makes two.  However, I have a (great-great?) great-grandfather IIRC whose last name was Zevin.  I wonder if there is any distant connection.

Answer (score 3):

There is a concept brought in Hilchos Sefiras Haomer that one of the reasons women shouldn't make a Bracha is because they are likely to forget one day. Not sure if it stands *Lehalacha*, but it would appear to apply here (where the person knows for sure that he will miss).

[On the other hand, it might be different here because of the surgery aspect]

This is definitely an interesting question.

Comment: _Mishna B'rura_ 489:3.

Answer (score 2):

chacham ben tzion aba shaul in chelek alef-36 and chelek 3-16-5 understand the behag differently. he says even the behag agrees that its 49 seperate mitzvot . just that if you miss a day, youre lacking the continuous flow and therefore youre out. 
rav soloveichik is quoted also as understanding such. 
acc. to this , one can begin even if they know they will be unable to finish bec until you miss youve fulfilled seperate mitzvos. see there its a beautiful piece. 
however the Chida in more be'etzba 217 says that if you miss a day , then all of your berachos are retroactively levatala. so the chida seems to understand that its 1 big mtzva. accordingly, if one will be unable to finish, he should not begin. 
see daily halacha from rabbi eli mansour online - he has a quote from rav elyashiv on this  there is a shiur by rav nissan kaplan on this forgot where .